# Text Strike Line Color Styling

Tags: html, css

How can I change the color of the the strike-through line?

If I give the strike tag a class and then use CSS to change the color, it also changes the text color. I just want to change the color of the line and not the text.

```css
h1 {
  color: #4287f5;
}

.strike {
  color: #eb1515;
}
```

```html
<h1><s class="strike">£1000</s></h1>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It's the same problem. Attaching a class to style the line also styles the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`text-decoration-color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color), although [browser support is spotty](https://caniuse.com/text-decoration)

```css
s {
  color: #4287f5;
  text-decoration-color: #eb1515;
}
```

```html
<s>Text</s>
```

Comment: I think you need to re-read the question.

Comment: sure did ... my bad, fixed

Comment: Can't get it working on the browsers I need to use. Seems quite a basic oversight in html.